# Do GoPro mounts use standard tripod points?

Tags: tripod, gopro, tripod-socket

I've been looking at some wearable camera mounts, and I get the impression that GoPro mounts are different from the standard tripod mount point.

Can I use my video camera with its standard screw-in tripod mount with a GoPro mount?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

GoPro cameras do not have a built in tripod mount(1/4-20). **They actually have a more specialized quick release clip built into the waterproof housing. To attach a GoPro unit to a tripod mount, you need the [GoPro Tripod Mount](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002RCLYXG)** which runs about $8 these days.

**To answer your question, if you want to mount a GoPro camera to a tripod, you need the Tripod mount accessory.** The various other mounts that you can get will allow you to mount the GoPro to things like a flat surface, curved surface, pivot arm, or a leather leash. You can pick these up in its "grab bag" mount kit as shown [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003U6Y1OC). Note - this does not come with the tripod mount.

**If you are asking about a video camera in addition to the GoPro, that will not work with any of the GoPro mount accessories, because it will not have the quick release GoPro mount.**

Here is an image of the GoPro standard housing with **built in quick release clip** and currently attached to the flat adhesive mount:

[image: GoPro with standard housing and quick release clip]

This is an image of the GoPro standard housing with the **Tripod Adapter** mounted to a tripod:

[image: GoPro standard housing with the Tripod Adapter]

Finally a closeup view of the tripod adapter:

[image: GoPro Tripod Adapter Mount]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering, but I think you've answered the opposite question. My camera is a Sony, not a GoPro. Can I stick that camera (with its standard screw-hole mount point) on my head with a GoPro helmet mount?

Comment: Your title and your body conflict in the question, so I tried to answer both. The answer to if you can stick a sony camcorder onto a gopro mount is no.

Comment: You're right. I've rewritten the title to be less ambiguous.

Comment: @billpg - Finally got myself a GoPro, ready to answer any future questions here :)

Comment: @dpollitt glad you took one for the team. ;)

Answer (score 2):

For attaching a regular camera onto a GoPro mount, you can get an adapter. ie something that screws onto the 1/4" tripod mount, and provides a GoPro style "two-prong" attachment.

For example:

- [K-Edge Go Big Universal Adapter](http://k-edge.com/shop/camera-mounts/go-big-universal-adapter-quarter/)

[image: K-Edge Go Big Universal Adapter]

- [Drift Universal Action Camera Mount Adapter](https://driftinnovation.com/collections/mounts/products/universal-action-camera-mount-adapter-3)

[image: Drift Mount Adapter]

- Or there are plenty of cheap, generic versions available on Ebay. Search for something like *gopro universal mount adapter*

[image: generic mount adapter]

These should work with any action camera that has a standard 1/4" tripod screw, including the Sony action cameras. Or you could use it with a regular compact camera - but it depends on the strength of the mounts and adapters, they may not be strong enough for a much heavier camera.

Answer (score 1):

This addresses GoPro camera to GoPro tripod.  I have discovered that to use my GoPro chest strap, you need a "male" thread that is slightly larger.  I am using very basic language (male, female, big, small) for 2 reasons: first, simplicity, and second, because I do not know the "size" or standard of each.  All I know is that both the male and female threads of GoPro attachments are slightly smaller than the smartphone holder that I want to employ.  Onward to look.  Hope I contributed :)